# How to publish with private beta users

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

**Final edit:**
Like the answer and some comments said, I only had to wait two days and now the app is published, thanks for the answers

I've create a list to users who can download my application, then I've tried to upload the internal published application on https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing/

but I get an error It is necessary to publish the application xxx to share it internally.

Can't I share the application without publish it? I've published it but only internally, I'm bit confused

EDIT:
I have published the app on internal tests with my tester user lists, but I don't have any url and it says

When you publish your application, a link to participate in the testing program will be included here.

this is the thing I don't understand, do I need to publish to production before to be able to test an internal version?

I'm confused because google seems to be asking me to upload the app to production that I want the clien to test... before upload it.

EDIT2: to clarify, on internal test it says publication completed, thats what cofusing me, because then to get a test url I need to publish my application but I already did that (on internal test)

Comment: It's not clear exactly at which step you're getting this error.

Comment: you can use internal test

Comment: I'm using internal test, now the state is pending publication, should I wait then?

Comment: Yes, only when it says published will it be available to users who have opted in. Don't forget to share the opt in URL with them so they can opt in!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I've tried to add some more context to the problem, sorry for my missunderstanding about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your app in alpha with the closed track. create a closed track then manage testers after publishing in alpha then assign that testers group to the app, this will generate an URL which needs to be shared with testers group.

Comment: I have my app on alpha with closed track testers assigned but yet I don't have any url. Do I have to upload my app to production? because it asks me to do so.

Comment: I've just gone through this procedure, and it takes 1-3 days before you get your URL. Check in your Play Console now and then, and you will get a notice about your app being published, even if it's just in alpha environment. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I thought google play was asking me to publish the app (to production) not that I had to wait, what confused me is the message pending publication I'm more used to iOS with testflight. thanks for the answer I'm going to wait then

Comment: Edit: thanks to both for the answer! it was like you said, I had to wait 2 days and now the app is published for internal test